# Passport.js - Send back data to react/redux app, while redirecting after login

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, redux, passport.js

I'm creating a React/Redux app and am new to setting up the backend with Node/Express and authentication with Passport. What I'd like to have happen is the user logs in, credentials are checked, and if user is found from database, redirect the user to the next page and return user's info so I can update reducer.

My endpoint to login works as I think it does, as I'm able to access req.user object and am getting back the correct user info upon successful authentication. Where I'm stuck is redirecting the user to another page, while also passing along that user's info so I may update redux store.

EDIT: So I updated response by sending user info after authentication as well as the next route to redirect the user. Since I'm using redux, I perform login action, and upon getting a response, I redirect user with window.location. This partially solves my problem as even though I redirect after logging in, I believe that after updating window.location, my redux store gets refreshed, and I lose any information I grabbed server side.

```
app.post('/api/login', passport.authenticate('local-login', { failureRedirect: '/login'}), (req, res) => {
    res.json({
  redirect: '/profile
  userInfo: req.user.dataValues})
  })
})

export const login = (email, password) => {
  return(dispatch) => {
    axios
    .post('/api/login', {
        email: email,
        password: password
    })
    .then(resp => {
      dispatch({
        type: 'LOGIN_USER',
        data: resp.data
      })
      window.location = resp.data.redirect
    })
    .catch(errors => {
      console.log(erros)
    })
  }
}
```

Comment: After authenticating the user, you can send the user a token. In the front end, you can expect this token and upon receiving it send the user to "/" then from / you call a service that contains the user data (if your api is designed this way)

Comment: @Beto At the moment, I'm only returning back user info from my database, but I know that it's better practice to use tokens when make API requests. Issue I run into now is that when I get user info back from API, I update redux store and if redux store is updated, I'd want to redirect the user, but updating the store has no effect. I also tried using window.location to redirect, but that only wipes out the store, which is not ideal.

Comment: If you want to redirect upon success from auth, I think you're going to want to use react router to redirect you to the authenticated route/component, not with window.location. Here's an example with react-router: https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/auth-workflow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're losing your state because you are forcing a page reload with `window.location = resp.data.redirect`. You should use a router with your application to do the url changes (such as [react-router-dom](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-router-dom)). You can programmatically change the urls by using pushState (or maybe hashRouting?) instead of redirecting the way you currently are.

Comment: Thanks for that! I did end up using react-router-dom and after dispatching redux action to login, i also passed in the history object so that after getting the response back from server, i can push state to the next url